# Local mercurial repository

Tags: mercurial

I want to understand how mercurial works on the server side. So I do some local experiment and can't understand what is going wrong.
I make two directories `/server` and `/client` then go to `/server`, make new directory `/server/repository`, go to `/repository` and call `hg init`.By this I have an hg repository.
Then I go to `/client` and call `hg clone file://path_to_server/server/repository`. It clones empty repository to the `/client` folder. Then I create new file and put it under hg control doing `hg add file`, commit it and push. I expect a `file` in the `/server/repository/` but it's still empty.Maybe my expectations so naive and behaviour I expect is incorect. It also might be really doubtful thing  - moving files locally by pushing from `/client` to `/server` without any  command in `/server/repo/` folder. In this case I hope anybody explain why that doesn't word this way and what should I do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [`hg update`](https://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hg.1.html#update) on the server repository.

The [working directory](https://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/WorkingDirectory) (which is the set of files you see in the filesystem) is not automatically updated when new changesets arrive either from pulling or pushing changes from another repo.

Good Luck!

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you mate!

Comment: It's usually pointless to do that at the server side. Why would you want a working directory there? Just let everyone push to it and clone/pull from it. No need for any files to be checked out.

Comment: @Ringding I want to register users, check permissions, control threads and etc. I can turn on server that will be handle all request, not directly from the user but from my server. Or I can handle requests by myself. That's why these questions like "what the representation of mercurial request?", "how to get headers?" or "how to serve the request from command line?" make sense for me.